# Alfred Workflow does not show my chrome profile

Tags: alfred

I am using Alfred 4.8 [1312] with powerpack. In my Preferences -> Web Bookmarks -> Google Chrome Bookmarks -> I get a dropdown with two profiles but recently I renamed my chrome profile and it does not appear to be picking this up.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?